# Is there a way to act before the scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I discovered that

```
e.preventDefault()
e.stopPropagation();
return false;
```

Do nothing if the triggering event is a scroll,

However, is there anyway to 'beat' the scroll event in firing order?

```
body{
   width: 100%;
   height: 2000px;
}

$(document).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('body').css('overflow','auto')
    },100)
});
```

The above code does not work, the event trigger fires but the document scrolls before overflow is hidden every single time. however if the overflow can be hidden before the event propagates then this would work.

Is this possible?

I'm not interested in just preventing scrolling, I actually have element moving position on a scroll event. Things aren't as noticeable in Firefox, however in chrome(and especialy IE), the move clearly happens after the scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the following events:

- wheel     (when you use the mouse wheel)
- mousedown (when you click on the scroll bar of the doc to scroll)
- keydown   (ctrl+home, ctrl+hend, down-up arrow, pgdown and pgup: keyboard scrolling)

If you need to stop the scrolling at all it's enough you add the preventDefault.

These are fired before scroll event.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).on('wheel mousedown keydown', function(e){
  if (e.type == 'wheel' || e.target.tagName == 'HTML' ||
      (e.type == 'keydown' && ((e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode  == 36 || e.which == 35)) ||
                               (!e.ctrlKey && (e.keyCode  == 33 || e.which == 34 || e.which == 38|| e.which == 40))))
     ) {
    console.log(e.type + ' event');

    //you may want to prevent the scroll: add next line + return;
    //
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('body').css('overflow','auto')
    },100)
  }
});
```

```css
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question fully. Do you want to disable scrolling just the moment user tries to scroll? Well by default when we just scroll the mouse wheel the browser seem to scroll by 114px anyway. So perhaps whatever we do it will scroll the window by this amount on mousewheel event. If you juts want to prohibit scrolling you could force the window to remain at a particular scroll position with `$(window).scrollTop(myvalue)`. E.g:

```
var currpos = $(window).scrollTop();
$(document).on('scroll', function(e){
    $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    $(window).scrollTop(currpos);
    setTimeout(function(){
       $('body').css('overflow','auto')
    },100)
});
```