# Replace vertical scroll by horizontal scroll vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

I want to disable and replace the vertical scroll with horizontal one in Vanilla JavaScript. I am blocked when I try to replace my scroll values. I trust there is a simple simple (really simple) solution to that !

```
/* We define our function  */
function replaceVerticalScrollByHorizontal() {
  let scrollX = window.scrollX; /* Horizontal ➡️ */
  let scrollY = window.scrollY; /* Vertical ⬇️ */
  console.log({scrollX, scrollY});

  if (scrollY !== 0) {
    /* If there is a changement in verticalScroll  ⬇️ */
    const tempScrollY = scrollY; /* We create a temporary var to stock our scrollY value */
    scrollX = scrollY; /* Horizontal = Vertical */
    scrollY = 0; /* We reset the vertical because we don't want any vertical scroll */
    window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY); /* We scroll to our value */
    scrollY = tempScrollY; /* We replace the value of our vertical var with the temporary one */
  }
  /* If no verticalScroll changement, exit of this function  ⬇️ */
  return;
}

/* Listener on window once we start scrolling, we run our function  */
window.addEventListener('scroll', replaceVerticalScrollByHorizontal);
```

There is a little jsfiddle with my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/zynj64m7/2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to only effect the mouse wheel event you can try using the "wheel" event. This works in Firefox and Chrome from my testing. Not IE (edit: actually the event does fire just the method I used to scroll doesn't seem to work so you could possibly get this to work in IE as well).

Then use `event.deltaY` to determine if the scroll was vertical and prevent it. Also use the direction of `event.deltaY` to scroll some direction horizontally instead (I Multiplied by 5 because it seemed a bit slow but you can change the scroll amount to w/e).

Update of you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zynj64m7/3/)

```js
    /* We define our function  */
    function replaceVerticalScrollByHorizontal(event) {
     if (event.deltaY != 0) {
       // manually scroll horizonally instead
        window.scroll(window.scrollX + event.deltaY * 5, window.scrollY);
        
        // prevent vertical scroll
       event.preventDefault();
      }
      return;
    }

    /* Listener on window once we start scrolling, we run our function  */
    window.addEventListener('wheel', replaceVerticalScrollByHorizontal);
```

```html
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
  <h1>Hellooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</h1>
```

Comment: Hey ! Thank you for your 'solution', but wheel does not prevent other scroll type (like arrow keys for exemple), I can add another listener about that, but I think the proper way is to use 'scroll' event ! :) Thank you again.

Comment: The problem with the scroll event is that it only fires after the scroll has already occurred. So even if you fix it to scroll horizontally it will look janky because you will have to effectively un-scroll the vertical scroll and then scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thanks ! I did not know that ! :o The way to accomplish that is so to use different addEventListener !

Comment: If you want to hide the vertical scroll bar (to prevent scrolling that way) you can use the css `overflow-y: hidden;`
Or for a list of all events you need to fix look that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163669/is-there-a-way-to-act-before-the-scroll-event)

Comment: `preventDefault()` no longer seems to work since the scroll event is considered passive: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6662647093133312. 
Working version: https://jsfiddle.net/levigutt/c9L8k3rs/1/