# JavaScript fully disable scrolling on an element

Tags: javascript, scroll, overflow

This question is not about using `overflow: hidden` to stop the user from scrolling. It's about ensuring that an element cannot be scrolled by another script.

I've prepared the following example to illustrate a case where an unwanted scrolling might occur (I'm aware that adding `position: relative` to the `tr` or `td` will solve the scrolling the issue. I'm asking if there is a way to disable the scrolling using javascript or html).

```js
var dom = document.querySelector("tbody");


for (var index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  cell.appendChild(document.createElement("input")).id = "x" + index;
  cell.appendChild(document.createElement("label")).htmlFor = "x" + index;
  row.appendChild(cell);
  dom.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
#div1 {
  height: 200px;
}

#div2 {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

input {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

label::before {
  content: "label";
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="height: 200px;">
  <div id="div2" style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll;">
    <table>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried overwriting all the properties (to my knowledge) that could alter the vertical scrolling.

```
function define(prototype, propertyName, declaration) {
    Object.defineProperty(prototype, propertyName, {
        configurable: false,
        value: declaration,
        writable: false
    });
}

define(dom, "scrollIntoView", function () { });
define(dom, "scrollBy", function () { });
define(dom, "scrollTo", function () { });
define(dom, "scroll", function () { });
define(dom, "scrollTop", 0);
```

Without any success, I also tried to add a `scroll` event listener to scroll element back to `0`.

```
dom.addEventListener("scroll", function(){if(dom.scrollTop) dom.scrollTop = 0; });
```

But this functionality is jumpy/flashy on certain browsers (IE, Edge).

Comment: Is this output from APEX or custom output that has been added to a region? I'm trying to figure out where these style attributes came from (they are not valid). Could you please show all the HTML? I see a label, but no related item. Where is the item?

Comment: Details matter. Please provide the details I'm looking for.

Comment: But now there's no label element.

Comment: Isn't the scrolling happening when a user clicks the label?

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce the exact situation based on the code provided. However, I was able to observe some "scroll" behavior when a label was clicked and its related element was positioned outside of the viewport. I was able to prevent this behavior with this:

```
$('label').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I did not observe the behavior with elements other than a span. If the above solution isn't sufficient, please provide a link to an APEX app export that I can use to test more thoroughly.

Comment: Scrolling was indeed caused by a label, but like I said this question is asking for a way to disable scrolling for an element.

Comment: Scrolling is just default behavior for other events. Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163669/is-there-a-way-to-act-before-the-scroll-event